# kafka-connector with java in gradle enviroment

Tags: java, gradle, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

i'm studying kafka with spring. now i want to make kafka-connector.
i heard that kafka-connector can't execute itself. so i hav to compile my java files and add that as plugin. ( and for this im using gradle.)

here's the my gradle.

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

group 'org.pipeline'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.9.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.kafka:connect-api:2.5.0'
    implementation 'org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client:7.9.2'
    implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.24'
    implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.24'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.1'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.1'
}

jar{
    from{
        configurations.implementation.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

and when i execute 'gradle-jar' i've got errror code below

```
Build file '/MyPath/project-name/elsticsearch-kafka-connector/build.gradle' line: 25

Could not determine the dependencies of task ':jar'.
> Resolving dependency configuration 'implementation' is not allowed as it is defined as 'canBeResolved=false'.
  Instead, a resolvable ('canBeResolved=true') dependency configuration that extends 'implementation' should be resolved.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

help plz?

Comment: I don't think you need the `jar {}` block. The java plugin will already know how to build a JAR. You might need the shadowJar plugin, though

Comment: Thanks for your comment :>  i'm gonna try